# "Does it make sense?" or "Do you understand me?"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, questions, business-language

Suppose I tell something to my companion and I want to make sure he understands me. I thought I may simply ask "Do you understand me?". But recently I heard that in such cases I should ask "Does that make sense?" instead. Is this true? Which option is appropriate to use in business communication?

Comment: It should be "does *that* make sense" if you are referring to what you just said.

Comment: I think this is a useful and important question. It's a shame it was closed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"Do you understand me?" slightly carries the implication that it is your fault if you do not understand.

"Does it make sense?" carries the implication that it is my fault if you do not understand.

So politeness suggests that the latter is better.

Comment: By "my" do you mean the speaker and by "your" do you mean the "listener"?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't be too keen on doing business with anyone who asked "Does it make sense?" in a written communique concerning the project we might be collaborating on. Give me someone who knows what they're talking about, please!

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this difference occurs as a result of the difference in subject; in the first construction 'you' are the one with questionable ability to comprehend, while in the second, 'it' is the one with questionable comprehensibility.

So yes, I would agree that the latter is more polite, although the first is more direct (it requires a response with relation to exactly how much the listener understands). However, it must be noted that ultimately tone and body language tend to convey more in face-to-face interaction, especially for business communication.

Comment: There is also a known psychological factor that if the listener doesn't understand, they may not feel comfortable saying that. If the questioner is of higher status, or someone they do not work with on a regular basis, the listener may say "yes, I understand" simply to save face even if they don't. Therefore, if you're worried about true understanding, using an equivalent of "does it make sense" works better.

Answer (score 3):

In many contexts the two sentences are equivalent.

In *some* situations, "Do you understand me?" carries overtones of superiority, intimidation, etc. Correspondingly, in some other situations, "Does it make sense?" implies submissiveness, uncertainty, etc.

In a business communication I would avoid using *either* form. Partly because of the possiblity the recipient might pick up on either of the above overtones (which presumably you wouldn't intend), but mainly because I feel they are both a bit informal for the context.

Better by far to say something like *Please do not hesitate to ask for clarification if required*.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a small difference.

"Do you understand me?" is usually confirming, in a straightforward manner, whether somebody understands the facts/argument of what you have said.

"Does that make sense?" (usually with "that", at least in UK English) can mean something similar, but is a more loaded question, implying that the other party *should* or has an *obligation* to understand what was said, and that if they don't, they are in some way stupid or disobedient. If the person saying this is your boss, they're not really enquiring about your ability to follow their argument, but effectively saying "Now do as you're told".

Comment: I think this is wrong. Especially the bit about "does that make sense?". That is a much more polite way of asking if you made yourself understood to the listener, not the opposite like you are saying.

Comment: Well, in the UK, this is really how I observe it being used. If your boss says "Does that make sense?" they're really not trying to be polite and check they've made themselves understood, but rather assert their authority and the fact that you *should* have understood them/the idea first time. But you could always try it and see if you get fired, I suppose...

Comment: I have lived in the UK myself and I am married to an Englishman, and I still disagree.

Comment: @masarah: Perhaps your hubby is the non-confrontational type. In any case, he probably doesn't use "boss-speak" with you. Unfortunately many bosses *do* project their authority in the way Neil suggests, and I'd be surprised if this were a peculiarly British trait.

Comment: Never heard this uses in the way Neil mentions. I choose to not continue arguing over this, but I hope that @Andrey doesn't only look at this answer when checking what the correct usage is...

Comment: Why the downvote? Totally agree with Neil on this one. *Does that make sense?* could certainly be condescending, especially depending on the tone of voice that goes with it.

Comment: @Jimi "A downvote? Does that make sense?" ;)

Answer (score 2):

"Do you understand me?" seems very rough because of "me". I would change it to "do you understand?". By asking this it seems that the listener might not understand, which implies that you are not completely equal. This question sort of fits better if you are speaking to someone who doesn't really speak your language. So the understanding means that you might not actually be capable of understanding.

"Does that make sense?" Is a nice way of asking if you are making yourself "understood" But more towards a politeness as @Henry says. I would use this option over the other one any day. And I think that is the best you can do.

Good luck:)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that both have their tendency to offend.  Literally, questions are questions; however, we are talking now about sociolinguistics and implied verbiage.  Regarding "Does that make sense?"— is still a little offensive and condescending.  Typically used in verbiage to a child from a parent, it seems that this has become prevalent in the workplace these days.   Think about how the respondent might answer, yes or no, and if no, then you might have just put the word 'idiot' behind the phrase. "Does that make sense, idiot?"

Answer (score 0):

altenatively:

> Is what I just said, intelligible?

or

> Is what I just said, comprehensible?

Answer (score 0):

In American english, many will use this phrase in a disciplinary manner to advise or reinforce to the listener that no argument or failure to comply will be tolerated.  ie: "Do not do that again.  Do you understand me?" 
Since the phrase is frequently used in this manner, it takes a negative or angry connotation in general speech and will frequently draw an unintended negative response.  If making a genuine request to an equal to confirm that you are being understood I would more likely choose a phrase like "Am I making sense to you?", or more casually "Do you get me?"

Answer (score 0):

I generally go with a simple:

> Is this explanation okay..?

As it sounds neutral and encourages the receiver to provide feedback.

If I used pronouns while asking for feedback, like "Did *you* understand..", "Did *I* explain this..", .. it generally makes the receiver feel like you might take their feedback negatively or take offense if they were not able to understand.